# resize Console c# .framework

Tags: c#, console

Excuse me for the question, here I put the cmd in fixed size, that the user cannot resize it with the mouse,

I had the same case in C++.

```
HWND consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
SetWindowLong(consoleWindow, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(consoleWindow, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX & ~WS_SIZEBOX);
```

But I don't have any idea for C#, in the meantime I made the principle of launching a threading

```
int x = Console.WindowWidth;
int y = Console.WindowHeight;

while (true)
{
     if (Console.WindowWidth != x && Console.WindowHeight != y)
     {
           Console.SetWindowSize(x, y);
     }
 }
```

But if you know another method, impossible to find in the microsoft doc, or other. Unless I looked wrong.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You want to prevent the user from resizing the console window? Can I ask why you'd force this?

Comment: because once the dimensions are set I don't want the user to be able to modify the window, if I display the text in the middle I don't want the user to be able to shrink the window and everything will be unsettled.

Comment: That `&&` should be an `||`, otherwise they can change the size in one direction and then the other.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, hope it will help. Taken from [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1aa43c6c-71b9-42d4-aa00-60058a85f0eb/c-console-window-disable-resize?forum=csharpgeneral)

```
class Program
{
    private const int MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;
    public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
    public const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xF020;
    public const int SC_MAXIMIZE = 0xF030;
    public const int SC_SIZE = 0xF000;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int nPosition, int wFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr handle = GetConsoleWindow();
        IntPtr sysMenu = GetSystemMenu(handle, false);

        if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
            DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_MINIMIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
            DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_MAXIMIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
            DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_SIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

}
```

**You need this:**

```
DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_MINIMIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_MAXIMIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_SIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
```

The first one prevent user from closing console window, the second one prevent user from minimizing console window, the third one prevent user from maximizing console window and the last one prevent the use from re-sizing console window.

Comment: Thank you, yes that's what I just used, it's very functional. I wanted to publish too quickly

Comment: Nice! I'm glad you made it!

Comment: Links to external sites are discouraged since they may be broken over time. Please try to include the relevant code sample directly in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I misapplied what I found, I restart it if I'm not the only one in this case, I did as in C++, I used the win32 api,

```
class Affichage
{
    #region win32
    private const int MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;
    public const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xF020;
    public const int SC_MAXIMIZE = 0xF030;
    public const int SC_SIZE = 0xF000;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int nPosition, int wFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
    #endregion
```

You can have more orders here  [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand)

```
IntPtr handle = GetConsoleWindow();
        IntPtr sysMenu = GetSystemMenu(handle, false);

        if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_MAXIMIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
            DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_SIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
        }
```